# Starting with Number and Ending with Character in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I just started learning AngularJs So sorry for dump question. I have requirement to validate the field which will start with number and end with 'M' character eg:- 10M, 5M, 200M etc. please any one help me how to do it in angular js.

Comment: Add some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-pattern` in your input field e.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="regex" />
```

and in your controller define `regex` as

```
$scope.regex = '\\d+M';
```

And you can check in your html, if input is valid or not like this:

```
input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code>
```

This will work well with `ng-messages` directive for form validation.

[Read More](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ngPattern** directive to validate by matching a **regular expression**:

[Angular docs: ngPattern directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

The pattern you need is `\d+M` (a sequence of 1..n digits, followed by an 'M'), you can try it out on the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provide a usefull directive [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) that you can apply on an input.

For your problem, you can use this code :

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^\d+[M]$/" ng-model="model" id="input"  />
```

*Explanation*

`/d` means digits only

`+` means at least one

`[M]` means M characters only